# How to extract out the values from multiline string using regex in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string in Javascript which has a multiline data of a person, its coming out from a single data source bundled with newline chars so the string looks somewhat like this:

```
First Name: ABC
Last Name: XYZ
Address:
     123, 5th Steeet
     City Name
     State Name (Country)
```

So, I am trying to bifurcate the values of the string into separate variables, I but when it comes to matching from 2nd line the regex engine is not skipping the text before the colon (:).

This is what I am doing using the Script:

```
var Details = // Text as shown above;
$("#fName").val(Details.match((?![First Name: ])[^\n]+)); // Works Correctly
$("#LName").val(Details.match(((?!\n)(?![Last Name: ])[^\n]+)); // Not Skipping anything instead returning the whole 1st line 
$("#Address1").val(Details.match((?!\n\n)(?![Address: ])[^\n]+)); // same first line
$("#Address2").val(Details.match((?!\n\n)(?![Address: ])[^\n\n]+)); // same first line
$("#Address3").val(Details.match((?!\n\n)(?![Address: ])[^\n\n\n]+));// same first line
```

I am a novice in regex and currently learning regular expression but haven't figured out how to start matching from a desired line. The string will always have same format only the value of First Name, Last Name: & Address lines will change as I am fetching it from dynamic data source.

Answer (score 2):

Since the format is the same, a *single* regular expression would be a lot easier. Match `First Name:` followed by characters, `Last Name:` followed by characters, and then each line following an `Address`:

```js
const str = `First Name: ABC
Last Name: XYZ
Address:
     123, 5th Steeet
     City Name
     State Name (Country)`;
const [, firstName, lastName, ...address] = str.match(
  /^First Name: (\S+)\nLast Name: (\S+)\nAddress:\s+(.+)\n\s+(.+)\n\s+(.*)/m
);
console.log(firstName);
console.log(lastName);
console.log(address);
```

For multiple matches in the same string, use a global regex:

```js
const re = /^First Name: (\S+)\nLast Name: (\S+)\nAddress:\s+(.+)\n\s+(.+)\n\s+(.*)/gm;
const str = `First Name: ABC
Last Name: XYZ
Address:
     123, 5th Steeet
     City Name
     State Name (Country)

First Name: foo
Last Name: bar
Address:
     999
     some city
     some state
`;
let match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  const [, firstName, lastName, ...address] = match;
  console.log(firstName);
  console.log(lastName);
  console.log(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do this without any regular expressions:

```js
var Details = "First Name: ABC\nLast Name: XYZ\nAddress:\n     123, 5th Steeet\n     City Name\n     State Name (Country)";

var detailsArray = Details.split('\n');
console.log( detailsArray[0].split(':')[1].trim() );
console.log( detailsArray[1].split(':')[1].trim() );
console.log( detailsArray[3].trim() );
console.log( detailsArray[4].trim() );
console.log( detailsArray[5].trim() );
```